# onSuccess and onError not being fired in rtk query

Tags: node.js, reactjs, postgresql, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

```
const [login] = useLoginMutation({
        onSuccess: () => {
            console.log("Success");
            setAlertType("success");
            setAlertMessage("Login successful!");
            setOpenAlert(true);
        },
        onError: (error) => {
            console.log("Error: " + error);
            setAlertType("error");
            setAlertMessage(`Login failed: ${error}`);
            setOpenAlert(true);
        }
    });
```

Everything is working except that the onSuccess and onError doesn't fire. The query is successful and everything.

Answer (score 1):

`onSuccess` and `onError` are not options in RTK Query.

You can not just make up options and expect them to work. Maybe you confused that with options from another library?

Generally, the hooks do not have any lifecycle callbacks. You can defined lifecycle callbacks (different ones, with different names) on endpoint level, but not on component/hook level.

Comment: Looks like ChatGPT doesn't know everything.

Comment: ChatGPT is, unfortunately, just giving answers that sound plausible, not correct answers.

Comment: I just want to have an MUI alert based on the response code.

Comment: You can do `triggerFn(args).unwrap().then(() => {})`

Comment: The status code isn't being returned by the mutation hook

Comment: In the case of an error, that will throw, so you can `.catch` it and look at the error.

Comment: I want to get the 200 status code also. I want a conditional statement for 200 and 401.

Answer (score 0):

```
const submitLoginForm = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
try {
    const response = await login(loginData);
    
    if(response.error) {
        setAlertType("error");
        setAlertMessage("Incorrect username or password");
        setOpenAlert(true);
    } else if (response.data) {
        setAlertType("success");
        setAlertMessage(response.data.message);
        setOpenAlert(true);
    }

    dispatch(hide());
    refetchLogin();
} catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
}
```

}